# PIVOT in SQL gives error - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, pivot-table, oracle-sqldeveloper

The below query in Oracle SQL gives me a table which consists of ID, Key , Value. I want to convert the Keys to columns and Values as column values while keeping ID as the ID of the row. I tried a PIVOT query. But I get an error - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

> Initial SQL

```
SELECT * FROM API.publisher_message_queue_detail
WHERE message_seq_id 
IN (SELECT message_seq_id FROM API.publisher_message_queue WHERE status='N' AND MESSAGE_TYPE='RetailerNewConnection') ;
```

> Result Table

[image]

> I want to convert this table to

[image]

> The PIVOT query I tried

```
SELECT * FROM API.publisher_message_queue_detail
WHERE message_seq_id IN 
    (SELECT message_seq_id FROM API.publisher_message_queue WHERE status='N' AND MESSAGE_TYPE='RetailerNewConnection') 
    PIVOT(
    COUNT(message_seq_id)
    FOR MSG_KEY
    IN (
        'MobileNo',
        'ActivatedDate',
        'ActSimNo',
        'ActActdevice',
        'PmsProfileID',
        'PaymentMode',
        'AgentCode',
        'ActPrePost',
        'Sbu',
        'Channel',
        'SalesPath',
        'OrderId'
    )
  )
;
```

However, I get the below error. What is my mistake here?

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 5
```

Comment: Could you paste the data rather than image.

Comment: You should not use * but only the columns you want and any column not part of PIVOT will be grouped and shown as a row.

Comment: How do you expect the "values" in your desired output columns to be generated by a query where what you are selecting is a **count**? Disregard everything else about your problem for the moment, and just think about this simple question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a fan of using invented syntax for something that is pretty easy to write without it.  Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT mq.AgentCode, . . . ,  -- whatever columns define each row
       MAX(CASE WHEN mqd.msg_key = 'MobileNo' THEN mqd.msg_value END) as MobileNo,
       MAX(CASE WHEN mqd.msg_key = 'ActivatedDate' THEN mqd.msg_value END) as ActivatedDate,
       . . . 
FROM API.publisher_message_queue JOIN
     API.publisher_message_queue_detail mqd
     ON mqd.message_seq_id = mq.message_seq_id
WHERE mq.status = 'N' AND mq.MESSAGE_TYPE = 'RetailerNewConnection'
GROUP BY mq.AgentCode, . . . ;
```

Or if you want all columns from the parent table:

```
SELECT *
FROM API.publisher_message_queue JOIN
     (SELECT mqd.message_seq_id,
             MAX(CASE WHEN mqd.msg_key = 'MobileNo' THEN mqd.msg_value END) as MobileNo,
             MAX(CASE WHEN mqd.msg_key = 'ActivatedDate' THEN mqd.msg_value END) as ActivatedDate,
             . . . 
      FROM API.publisher_message_queue_detail mqd
      GROUP BY mqd.message_seq_id
     ) mqd
     USING (message_seq_id)
WHERE mq.status = 'N' AND mq.MESSAGE_TYPE = 'RetailerNewConnection';
```

Comment: I tried your second query. Why does it say '"FROM keyword not found where expected"?

Comment: By "invented syntax" you are probably referring to the `PIVOT` operator, "invented" by Oracle in version 11.1. If that's what you mean, note that `PIVOT` is (likely) implemented a bit more efficient than conditional aggregation; all the `CASE` expression in the `SELECT` clause of a conditional aggregate query must be evaluated separately, resulting in the same column being compared repeatedly to different values. The `PIVOT` implementation appears to use a more efficient way to do the same job. (I say "appears" since no one outside Oracle knows, but it is seen in somewhat better performance.)

Comment: @Kabilesh . . . You have to fill in the `. . . ` with similar lines of the same logic.  Be sure there is no comma before the `from`.